# Circular reference detected while serializing object. What is this error exactly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, serialization

I would like to serialize the `List<Question>` object to JSON data.

The code that I'm currently in my ASP.NET MVC application using is:

```
List<Question> questionList;            
            questionList = questionManager.GetquestionsByTestId(id);
            var listData = questionList.ToArray();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            string strData = serializer.Serialize(listData);

            JsonResult json = Json(strData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The code seems to result in the following error:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'TestEnvironment.Models.Question'.
```

what should be this error means ?

**Edited: Question Class**

```
public partial class Question : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

        private int _QuestionId;

        private string _QuestionText;

        private System.Nullable<int> _TopicId;

        private System.Nullable<int> _Marks;

        private System.Nullable<int> _QuestionTypeId;

        private System.Nullable<int> _ChapterId;

        private System.Nullable<int> _Weightage;

        private System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan> _ExpectedTimeToAnswer;

        private EntitySet<Answer> _Answers;

        private EntitySet<TestDetail> _TestDetails;

        private EntityRef<Chapter> _Chapter;

        private EntityRef<QuestionType> _QuestionType;

        private EntityRef<Topic> _Topic;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnQuestionIdChanging(int value);
    partial void OnQuestionIdChanged();
    partial void OnQuestionTextChanging(string value);
    partial void OnQuestionTextChanged();
    partial void OnTopicIdChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnTopicIdChanged();
    partial void OnMarksChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnMarksChanged();
    partial void OnQuestionTypeIdChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnQuestionTypeIdChanged();
    partial void OnChapterIdChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnChapterIdChanged();
    partial void OnWeightageChanging(System.Nullable<int> value);
    partial void OnWeightageChanged();
    partial void OnExpectedTimeToAnswerChanging(System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan> value);
    partial void OnExpectedTimeToAnswerChanged();
    #endregion

        public Question()
        {
            this._Answers = new EntitySet<Answer>(new Action<Answer>(this.attach_Answers), new Action<Answer>(this.detach_Answers));
            this._TestDetails = new EntitySet<TestDetail>(new Action<TestDetail>(this.attach_TestDetails), new Action<TestDetail>(this.detach_TestDetails));
            this._Chapter = default(EntityRef<Chapter>);
            this._QuestionType = default(EntityRef<QuestionType>);
            this._Topic = default(EntityRef<Topic>);
            OnCreated();
        }

        [Column(Storage="_QuestionId", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
        public int QuestionId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._QuestionId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._QuestionId != value))
                {
                    this.OnQuestionIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._QuestionId = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("QuestionId");
                    this.OnQuestionIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_QuestionText", DbType="NVarChar(MAX)")]
        public string QuestionText
        {
            get
            {
                return this._QuestionText;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._QuestionText != value))
                {
                    this.OnQuestionTextChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._QuestionText = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("QuestionText");
                    this.OnQuestionTextChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_TopicId", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> TopicId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._TopicId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._TopicId != value))
                {
                    if (this._Topic.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                    {
                        throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                    }
                    this.OnTopicIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._TopicId = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("TopicId");
                    this.OnTopicIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_Marks", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> Marks
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Marks;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Marks != value))
                {
                    this.OnMarksChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Marks = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Marks");
                    this.OnMarksChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_QuestionTypeId", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> QuestionTypeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._QuestionTypeId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._QuestionTypeId != value))
                {
                    if (this._QuestionType.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                    {
                        throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                    }
                    this.OnQuestionTypeIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._QuestionTypeId = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("QuestionTypeId");
                    this.OnQuestionTypeIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_ChapterId", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> ChapterId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ChapterId;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._ChapterId != value))
                {
                    if (this._Chapter.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue)
                    {
                        throw new System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException();
                    }
                    this.OnChapterIdChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._ChapterId = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("ChapterId");
                    this.OnChapterIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_Weightage", DbType="Int")]
        public System.Nullable<int> Weightage
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Weightage;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._Weightage != value))
                {
                    this.OnWeightageChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._Weightage = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Weightage");
                    this.OnWeightageChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Column(Storage="_ExpectedTimeToAnswer", DbType="Time")]
        public System.Nullable<System.TimeSpan> ExpectedTimeToAnswer
        {
            get
            {
                return this._ExpectedTimeToAnswer;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((this._ExpectedTimeToAnswer != value))
                {
                    this.OnExpectedTimeToAnswerChanging(value);
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    this._ExpectedTimeToAnswer = value;
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("ExpectedTimeToAnswer");
                    this.OnExpectedTimeToAnswerChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Question_Answer", Storage="_Answers", ThisKey="QuestionId", OtherKey="QuestionId")]
        public EntitySet<Answer> Answers
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Answers;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Answers.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Question_TestDetail", Storage="_TestDetails", ThisKey="QuestionId", OtherKey="QuestionId")]
        public EntitySet<TestDetail> TestDetails
        {
            get
            {
                return this._TestDetails;
            }
            set
            {
                this._TestDetails.Assign(value);
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Chapter_Question", Storage="_Chapter", ThisKey="ChapterId", OtherKey="ChapterId", IsForeignKey=true)]
        public Chapter Chapter
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Chapter.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                Chapter previousValue = this._Chapter.Entity;
                if (((previousValue != value) 
                            || (this._Chapter.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                {
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    if ((previousValue != null))
                    {
                        this._Chapter.Entity = null;
                        previousValue.Questions.Remove(this);
                    }
                    this._Chapter.Entity = value;
                    if ((value != null))
                    {
                        value.Questions.Add(this);
                        this._ChapterId = value.ChapterId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._ChapterId = default(Nullable<int>);
                    }
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Chapter");
                }
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="QuestionType_Question", Storage="_QuestionType", ThisKey="QuestionTypeId", OtherKey="QuestionTypeId", IsForeignKey=true)]
        public QuestionType QuestionType
        {
            get
            {
                return this._QuestionType.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                QuestionType previousValue = this._QuestionType.Entity;
                if (((previousValue != value) 
                            || (this._QuestionType.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                {
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    if ((previousValue != null))
                    {
                        this._QuestionType.Entity = null;
                        previousValue.Questions.Remove(this);
                    }
                    this._QuestionType.Entity = value;
                    if ((value != null))
                    {
                        value.Questions.Add(this);
                        this._QuestionTypeId = value.QuestionTypeId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._QuestionTypeId = default(Nullable<int>);
                    }
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("QuestionType");
                }
            }
        }

        [Association(Name="Topic_Question", Storage="_Topic", ThisKey="TopicId", OtherKey="TopicId", IsForeignKey=true)]
        public Topic Topic
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Topic.Entity;
            }
            set
            {
                Topic previousValue = this._Topic.Entity;
                if (((previousValue != value) 
                            || (this._Topic.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
                {
                    this.SendPropertyChanging();
                    if ((previousValue != null))
                    {
                        this._Topic.Entity = null;
                        previousValue.Questions.Remove(this);
                    }
                    this._Topic.Entity = value;
                    if ((value != null))
                    {
                        value.Questions.Add(this);
                        this._TopicId = value.TopicId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this._TopicId = default(Nullable<int>);
                    }
                    this.SendPropertyChanged("Topic");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private void attach_Answers(Answer entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Question = this;
        }

        private void detach_Answers(Answer entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Question = null;
        }

        private void attach_TestDetails(TestDetail entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Question = this;
        }

        private void detach_TestDetails(TestDetail entity)
        {
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            entity.Question = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means pretty much what it says.

A circular reference means that a class has a reference to itself within the serializable properties.

I'm guessing that your Question-class has a property of type Question?
The JSON-Serializer is not able to serialize this unfortunately..

You could attempt to write your own serializer, but the simplest solution would be to change that property to be a different class.

If this is not correct, please post the code for your Question-class in your question.

Comment: well I did not found such possibility, but see the question i have added my class over there.But I found Topic as return type of property Topic.same for Chapter. so does it encounter error ? This class is generated by Linq-to-sql framework. by drag -drop table on dbml file.

Comment: How to know for which property this exception is arriving. or how can we check that particular property or member of object is not able to to serialize.

Comment: Yes, as long as you have an entity referring to itself you will get a circular error.

Comment: okay , how to resolve it then ? please don't tell me to use [Scriptignore] because i want to use these list in application. though i have accepted but need here explanation and how can i resolve this issue?